# Probability of $A<B$ when $A$, $B$ are random variable with different distribution?

Tags: probability, random-variable, exponential-distribution

Preparing exams, I ran into the following problem:

---

> Edit: it shouldn't be represented as it was. Added the storkes.

Let $A$, $B$ be two independent variables having probability distribution:
$$
\require{cancel}
\cancel{P(A = a) =} f_a(t) = \begin{cases} \lambda_ae^{-\lambda_a t} &, x \geq 0 \\ 0 &, x < 0 \end{cases}\\
\cancel{P(B = b) =} f_b(t) = \begin{cases} \lambda_be^{-\lambda_b t} &, x \geq 0 \\ 0 &, x < 0 \end{cases}
$$
Or in short, having exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_b$, respectively.

What is the probability of $A < B$?

---

What I thought to do is to do the following integral since the value of possible $A$ is bounded by $B$:
$$
\displaystyle \int^{\infty}_{0} \left( \int^{f_b(t)}_{0} f_a(t) dt\right)dt = \int^{\infty}_0 e^{-\lambda_a\lambda_b e^{-\lambda_b t}} dt
$$
which produces an integral using the exponential integral function $E_1(x)$, which is very weird as an exam problem. But where did I think wrong and how should I approach this problem?

Comment: That integral is wrong.  For example if you want $P(A <b)$ then the upper limit should probably be $b$ rather than  $f_b(t)$

Comment: Ahhhhhh yes you're right. Gotta think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You integrate the joint distribution $f_A(a)f_B(b)$ over the region $a<b$

$$P(A<B) = \int^{\infty}_{0}  \int^{\color{blue}{b}}_{0} f_A(a)f_B(b) \,\color{red}{da} \,\color{red}{db}$$

---

In your question you have several issues

- You are referring to probabilities like $P(A=a)$, but these are zero. Your function $f_A$ is a *density* function, and that's not the same as a probability.
- Your integral uses $dt$ twice
- You have the density as limit of the integrand instead of the variable

These last two points I have coloured in the function above. You can compare it to your function below where I coloured it the same.

$$\displaystyle \int^{\infty}_{0} \left( \int^{\color{blue}{f_b(t)}}_{0} f_a(t) \color{red}{dt}\right)\color{red}{dt}$$

Comment: +1.  "Using $\mathrm{d}t$ twice," although a valid concern, is not especially a problem here because the "$t$" in $f_a(t)$" would ordinarily be understood as bound to the inner "$\mathrm{d}t$" rather than the outer one.

Comment: @whuber I stated the double use of $dt$ but actually my concern was mostly with the occurrence of $t$ in the bounds as well as in the integrand $$ \int^{f_b(t)}_{0} f_a(t) dt$$ I find this very confusing. Can it be considered technically correct?

Comment: Thanks alot. About the first one, I totally get it but also I always wondered: how do I, without using English, illustrate the statement "$X$ is a discrete random variable having $f(x)$ as its distribution function"?

Comment: And about the double $dt$ problem — I originally also thought it was bad so I differentiate them using $t_a, t_b$. However, as I go through the textbook I found more and more examples using it as nothing weird, so I adapted it since it saves time. Maybe should keep using $t_a, t_b$, after all.

Comment: The interpretation is that all occurrences of "$t$" in the integrand are bound to the "$t$" in the differential "$\mathrm{d}t.$"  The "$t$" in the upper limit *cannot* reference that $t$ and so must be a different variable.  So, although such notation is dangerous--and definitely should be avoided, especially by beginners--it still works.